# How can I make the music player on this page to play continuously, even if you are going from the front page to a sub-page?

Tags: wordpress, navigation, menu, pages

I know that having a music player on a website isn't necessary nowadays. But I have a client that really wants one on their website. The problem is making the music player play constantly (the user can control it) between pages without it reloading when you click a link.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't believe this is generally achievable with WordPress. It requires a website to be developed using a Single Page App (SPA) framework so that the entire page doesn't reload as you click on links. Perhaps you could compromise with your client by offering a player that pops out into a separate window?